# Switching content types but default values weren't set

Tags: office-365

Content types were created in the content type hub in Office 365 and published throughout the site collections and sites. Content types exist of fields and for some of these fields default values were set.

Suppose there 2 content types:
Knowledge - column Classification was added, default value 'Private'
Minutes - column Document Status was added, default value 'In Progress'

These content types were added to a document library on one of the sites.

An overview of the default values at document library (source of default value) level:
[image]

When a document was created, dragged or uploaded to the library the default values were set as expected.

When the properties of the document were edited and another content type was selected, the accompanying default value wasn't always set! Sometimes it worked ok… not funny…

I don't think this is the expected behavior and certainly expected the default value for the (changed) content type was set.

After some investigation there seemed different behavior on setting the default value in combination with how the document was placed in the library.
The initial content type of the library was Knowledge.

Drag a document
The default value was set correctly. When editing the properties and switching the content type to Minutes, the default value of the Document Status remained empty… Switching back to Knowledge, a default value was set to the field Classification.

Upload a document
The default value was set correctly. When editing the properties and switching the content type to Minutes, the default value of the Document Status was filled correctly… Switching back to Knowledge, a default value was set to the field Classification.

Create a document
The default value was set correctly. When editing the properties and switching the content type to Minutes, the default value of the Document Status was filled correctly… Switching back to Knowledge, a default value was set to the field Classification.

After a while, most of the time just minutes, try again… Now editing the properties of all variants and switching the content type result in not setting the default value. Weird.
This behavior was tested on 2 different tenants with the same result.

A possible solution is to set the default values at document library. 
This means when creating a site the default values have to be set again at each document library… besides this inconvenient behavior it's impossible to manage the default values for all sites at content type hub level.

What is the solution to publish default values from the content type hub and use these default values when a content type switch happens on a document?